# Winform label control text changes place

Tags: c#, winforms, label-control

I have a

```
labelControl.Text ="My name:";
```

Result is

```
:My name
```

Symbols changes place.

If I write `"&= My name"`, the result is `=& My name`.

How do I stop it from changing places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [`RightToLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft) property correctly. By default this should be `RightToLeft.Inherit`. But either your `Form` or your `Label` was set like:

```
labelControl.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

You need to set it to `RightToLeft.No` or `RightToLeft.Inherit` (if the parent control has it set to `No`).

Comment: Thanks!, found one place it was set to yes.